# External redirect template is not opening in new window

Tags: sxa

I need to create page item which should link to external page and also need to be part of the navigation.

To solve this, I created custom `external redirect` template under templates/projects and I picked `standard template, _navigable and redirect` from base template.

After doing all this steps, I can create item and assign external URL with option to open in new window. Issue which I am having is that redirect external link is not opening in new page. am I missing any steps? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1)

Your solution won't work until you add some logic for Sitecore / layout / Page that once there is this field on Page it needs to redirect.

Probably this would be a seperate component that will be part of standard values on your custom template.

I assume based on your description that you have currently only field where you specified External link but that's it.

2)

There is a Redirect template that you can use next to standard Pages as you are using SXA.

A redirect is a way to send both users and search engines to a different URL from the one they originally requested. For example, to redirect visitors who enter namewebsite.com/home-a in their browser to namewebsite.com/home-b. This is very useful when you want to redirect a specific page to a new location, change the URL structure of a site so that it appears higher up in the navigation, or even redirect users to another website entirely. You can also use the mapping tool to set up a 301/302 or server transfer redirect.

To add a redirect item:

[image]

In the Content Editor, right-click on the page where you want to specify your redirect, and click Insert, Redirect.

Enter a name for the redirect item and click OK.

In the Redirect section, enter the URL that you want to direct to and save your changes.

[image]

Taken from Official Sitecore SXA Documentation:
https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/redirect-a-url.html

It should exactly fulfill your requirements.

Answer (score -2):

You will need to handle this when you generate the link in the navigation.

If you are using Glass.Mapper, you can do something like:

```
@using (BeginRenderLink(externalRedirectItem, x => x.FieldWithLinkToPage))
{
    @externalRedirectItem.ItemName
}
```

Or, if you don't have Glass, you can do it with raw Sitecore:

```
@Html.Sitecore().BeginField("Field With Link To Page", externalRedirectItem)
@externalRedirectItem["Field With Link To Page"]
@Html.Sitecore().EndField()
```